# Can i use Rails 3 generators when i'm developing gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I want to use `rails genrate` command in gem development. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can follow this [guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html)